# Список блоков с разным вертикальным выравниванием и ховер

Tags: html, css

Переделываю список товаров. Выравняла изображение и название товара поверху, а цену и кнопку купить понизу, как тут [http://chikuyonok.ru...vertical-align/](http://chikuyonok.ru/2011/04/inline-vertical-align/)
Вот бьюсь, не могу сделать ховер для блока с товаром, если это вообще возможно. Прошу помощи!
Ссылка http://jsfiddle.net/vera17/kk459/1/

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понял, поправив 'display: inline' на 'display: inline-block' в классе 'product-wrapper' решит вашу проблему

Comment: И после этого блоки уже не будут одной высоты.

Comment: каюсь, понял не верно :)